# socket io повторная отправка сообщения на клиенте

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

Я пытаюсь поймать и вновь отправить сообщение (отправленное через socket io) от клиента к серверу. Я нахожусь на стороне клиента и используя вкладку Network в инструментах разработчика браузера Chrome пытался получить информацию о подключении чтобы вновь отправить сообщение, но все, что показывает Network это бинарное сообщение, без названия события. Я пытался использовать  `localStorage.debug='*'` , чтобы посмотреть названия событий, но он ничего не показывает. Посмотреть нужную информацию в js коде тоже не получается там все под обфускацией. Как можно получить информацию об отправленном сообщении чтобы в итоге привести это к примерно такому виду `socket.emit('eventServer', { data: 'Hello Server' });` или что-то похожее?

Comment: может wireshark

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov Спасибо, попробую использовать это.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, тебе надо распечатать в консоли клиента отправленное сообщение с клиента, тут пример кода

На клиенте:

```
    socket.emit('eventServer', { data: 'Hello server' })
    socket.on('eventServer', (data) => { 
     console.log('event server ...', data)
    })
```

На сервере:

```
    socket.on('eventServer', (data) => {
      socket.emit('eventServer', data)
    }
```

Comment: Вы поняли меня немного не верно,  `socket.emit('eventServer', { data: 'Hello server' })` - это я привел пример как в итоге по хорошему должно получиться. Мне не известна часть: " 'eventServer' " и " data: 'Hello server' " , те сайт отправляет запросы ,а я не знаю параметры этих запросов и моя главная задача их узнать. Код сайта под  обфускацией, а доступа к серверной части у меня нет, вот и ищу способ решения такой задачки.